Configure Samba correctly for TimeMachine and other shares
I have configured a Linux container on a Proxmox host as a Time Machine target.
However, every share is now displayed as a possible Time Machine target.
This is not the case with my Synology. There, only the share configured for Time Machine is also shown in the Mac settings for Time Machine.

I would like only the Time Machine share provided for this purpose to be available in the Time Machine settings.
Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this?
My smb.conf
#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]
   # Fruit global config
   min protocol = SMB2
   vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
   fruit:nfs_aces = no
   fruit:metadata = stream
   fruit:model = MacSamba
   fruit:posix_rename = yes
   fruit:veto_appledouble = no
   fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
   fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
   server min protocol = SMB2

   unix charset = UTF-8

   workgroup = WORKGROUP

   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

#### Networking ####
   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

   bind interfaces only = yes

#### Debugging/Accounting ####

   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

   max log size = 1000

   logging = file

   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

   server role = standalone server

   obey pam restrictions = yes

   unix password sync = yes

   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

   pam password change = yes

   map to guest = bad user

####### Misc #######
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================
[Share]
   path = /shares/Share
   fruit:time machine = no
   available = yes
   valid users = @root
   read only = no
   writeable=yes
   browseable=yes
   public = no
   guest ok = no
   create mask = 0755


[Time Machine]
   fruit:time machine = yes
   fruit:time machine max size = 500G
   path = /shares/Time_Machine
   available = yes
   valid users = @root
   read only = no
   writeable=yes
   browseable=yes
   public = no
   guest ok = no
   create mask = 0755

